# Error: "Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'"

Tags: javascript, object-expected

I am writing this in JS and trying to figure out what my editor is complaining about. Here is what I have:

```
document.write('<div id="email-widget"></div>');
  var widgetHTML = 
   <div id="email-widget-box">
    <div id="email-signup-form">
     <p><strong>Send deals directly to my inbox - Sign up now!</strong></p>
```

What is missing because my editor has 4 errors all for one line but I cannot figure this out. The errors are:

> Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'
>   Missing semicolon
>   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
>   Missing semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start off just fine:

```
var widgetHTML =
```

what follows that `=` should be a Javascript expression. Strings (`"..."`), numbers, variable names, function calls, any of those things combined with operators -- all would be fine.

But a bunch of HTML is *not* a Javascript expression.

```
<div id="email-widget-box">
 <div id="email-signup-form">
  <p><strong>Send deals directly to my inbox - Sign up now!</strong></p>
```

If you want to set `widgetHTML` to that HTML text, you'll need to make a string out of it:

```
var widgetHTML = '<div id="email-widget-box">' +
  '<div id="email-signup-form">' +
  '<p><strong>Send deals directly to my inbox - Sign up now!</strong></p>';
```

Comment: Well that explains everything.....I was given this script to use as a guide and with my limited JS knowledge saw that exact example of having + and ' ..' With the html inside single quotes. I said to this can't be right and removed them all. :/

Will have to revert to the original and start again. :). If I don't make mistakes, how will I ever learn anything. 

Thanks Paul.